# SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio: Line chart from single record

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have an issue, I have a report I am building I have several columns that I would like to use in a Line chart, but I cant seem to make it work, I can sort of make it work with a bar graph but its 9 items along a single x axis.  is there any way to use columns like rows in a chart?

thanks!

As requested here are some images:

Data:

[image]

Chart Design:

[image]

Chart with single axis (I would like a line graph but since there is only one row nothing shows up.)

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could post an image of what you have that you don't like, and an image of you goal.  The answer will likely depend on how you want it to look.

Comment: I have added images now, hope this helps!

Comment: In order to make this a line chart, you'll need to rearrange your data a bit.  
Ideally, you'd have all of those testprobe types as separate categories, and a simple sum (details) the in values area.
The series groups should be unnecessary in this case.
I tried to post an image, but I'm horrible at web stuff.

Comment: @Projectile_Leprosy I have made the probes categories, but I am having trouble with the sum details, how does one do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, your query return data should look something like this:

```
TestProbeDistance     Percentage
10                    90
50                    90
30                    80
20                    80
90                    30
```

Then your query becomes very simple, like this:

```
Select TestProbeDistance, Percentage
From Table
```

Then, your chart code should look like this (replace NCLAIMID with Testprobedistance and ID with percentage):
[image]

The result should look like this:
[image]

If you post your query, I can make sure that's what you need.

On edit Try this:

```
SELECT NUM02 as ResistanceOhms, '10PCT'
FROM audits where (formsubID=1) and (businessunit='25181001400')
UNION ALL
SELECT NUM03 as ResistanceOhms, '20PCT'
FROM audits where (formsubID=1) and (businessunit='25181001400')
UNION ALL
SELECT NUM04 as ResistanceOhms, '30PCT'
FROM audits where (formsubID=1) and (businessunit='25181001400')
...<snip>...
UNION ALL
SELECT NUM10 as ResistanceOhms, '90PCT'
FROM audits where (formsubID=1) and (businessunit='25181001400')
```

That should flatten it out nicely.

Comment: Here is my main issue, my data is in columns not in rows.  I have two ideas:  Either a temporary table created by a stored procedure, or perhaps some kind of view with a pivot?

Comment: here is my query: SELECT        Num02 AS ResistanceOhms10pct, Num03 AS ResistanceOhms20pct, Num04 AS ResistanceOhms30pct, Num05 AS ResistanceOhms40pct, 
                         Num06 AS ResistanceOhms50pct, Num07 AS ResistanceOhms60pct, Num08 AS ResistanceOhms70pct, Num09 AS ResistanceOhms80pct, 
                         Num10 AS ResistanceOhms90pct
FROM            Audits
WHERE        (FormSubID = 1) AND (BusinessUnit = '25181001400')