# SSRS 2012: Sparkline Chart Per Every Details Row

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have a stored procedure that returns data in this format:

```
Location  MorningSales  NoonSales  NightSales
A         12            6          32
B         20            43         12
```

I have my table displaying the above data in details (not grouped) format. I now want to add a sparkline at the end of each row, using the numbers in those three fields.
They should look something like this:

[image: Location A Sparkline]
[image: Location B Sparkline]

I just cannot for the life of me figure out how to setup category groups for each field.
I was able to have this result before by bringing in the data as multiple rows for each Location, i.e.:

```
Location  SalesTime  SalesCount
A         Morning    12
A         Noon       6
A         Night      32
B         Morning    20
B         Noon       43
B         Night      12
```

But for the purposes of speed, I had to pre-calculate my sums and avgs in a stored procedure, since SSRS seemed to take forever and a day to render the report when it calculated the aggregates itself.

Is there any way to pull off what I'm trying to do here?

I think my question is similar to this one:
[SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio: Line chart from single record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731177/sql-server-business-intelligence-studio-line-chart-from-single-record)

The accepted answer there is to rewrite the sql query and end up with something similar to the second dataset I showed here. If it can't be done any other way then fine, but I don't mind hacking and rigging to make it work for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below link helps you in finding the solution:

http://www.sqlcircuit.com/2012/11/ssrs-how-to-add-sparkline-in-tabular.html

Comment: Could you please summarize how this link would solve the problem?